# which one good consesus engine Raft or Kafka

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am using Hyperledger Fabric for one of my project. I am bit confused with Kafka and Raft which is better for production level.
For Kafka you need to configure broker how this would be different than raft

Comment: you can read all the details here 
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/orderer/ordering_service.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@fama,

From my personal experience, I would suggest you go with raft in the production

kafka will come with additional baggage such as zookeeper & kafka itself and many complained about connection issues

kafka & raft are distributed consensus mechanisms, but raft is matured

Comment: how to configure HLF consensus to raft, any document would be help full, In which part  i should can configure.

Comment: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/first-network/docker-compose-etcdraft2.yaml

Comment: Its docker-compose file, where i configure, whether i need to use kafa or raft ? In docker-compose file no where its declare has raft

Comment: You have to make some changes in the configtx file as well https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/first-network/configtx.yaml

Comment: Thank you, I need to use "EtcdRaft" in  OrdererType: EtcdRaft, need to give tls certificate. I can use cryptogen generated tls certificate or i need to create the tls certificate using fabric ca server

Comment: just change the orderer type to EtcdRaft else is same.